# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de ejecutar batch con java?

Tags: java

Hola que tal quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma de ejecutar archivos batch con java, las formas en que pienso que se puede hacer es haciendo todo desde java es decir por ejemplo tengo que ejecutar ciertos comandos via ssh pienso que podría conectarme desde java y ejecutar los comandos usando los objetos que me permitan hacer esto... otra forma pienso que es ejecutar desde java el puro archivo batch que contenga la conexion ssh y los comandos... y otra forma que he escuchado es utilizando un framework como spring pero la verdad no lo he usado... ¿ustedes que me recomiendan? saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Erikzon. Tu pregunta me resulta un poco confusa. Cuando te refieres a procesar batch te refieres a procesar un archivo .sh o .bat donde hay procesos del sistema operativo o te refieres a ejecutar un proceso de muchas transacciones como si fuese un batch?

Comment: Me refiero a procesar un archivo .sh o .bat donde hay procesos del sistema operativo.

Answer (score 4):

> quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma de ejecutar archivos batch con java

Tienes dos maneras de hacerlo. Una es utilizando [`Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("comando", new String[]{ "argumento" });
```

La otra es utilizando [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("comando", "argumento").start();
```

`"comando"` es el nombre de tu archivo (.bat, .sh) que vas a ejecutar.

La diferencia es que la primera es un método wrapper para crear una instancia de `ProcessBuilder` y ejecutar el proceso. Si quieres agregar configuración como en qué carpeta se encuentra el proceso a ejecutar, mandar la salida del proceso a un archivo log o a consola, entre otros, utilizar la segunda forma. Si no necesitas manejar nada de eso, utiliza la primera.

> otra forma pienso que es ejecutar desde java el puro archivo batch que contenga la conexion ssh y los comandos

Esto depende realmente de orden más que de Java en sí. Si tu configuración de conexión ssh puede variar mucho, entonces quizás convenga mantener dicha configuración en tu archivo de proceso (.bat, .sh). De lo contrario, si esa configuración es estática y no puede/debe ser alterada con tant facilidad, entonces quizás quieras "protegerlo" en el código Java. No hay una respuesta concreta para esto.

> otra forma que he escuchado es utilizando un framework como spring pero la verdad no lo he usado

[Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) realiza trabajo de procesamiento de datos por lotes. Por ejemplo, tienes una tabla con mil registros, necesitas que cada registro sea procesado en batch para producir cierta información, que la ejecución sea en paralelo, agregar tolerancia a fallos, etc, entonces para este escenario utilizas Spring Batch. Si quieres ejecutar un archivo .bat o .sh, Spring Batch no es probablemente lo que busques.

Comment: Gracias Luiggi te lo agradezco mucho. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo utilizando la clase [Runtime](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_runtime.htm) y mediante el método [exec()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_dir.htm):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\path\\miarchivo.bat");
```

Comment: Si esta bien pero también he visto que puedo hacer una conexion ssh desde java (http://programacion.net/articulo/conectar_via_ssh_con_java_1163) o desde un archivo .bat y ejecutarlo como dices ¿Cual es la mejor forma?

Comment: bueno eso ya no pertenece a la pregunta "¿Cual es la mejor forma de ejecutar batch con java?" , quieres agregar otra pregunta especificando lo que comentas o te contesto aquí?

Comment: Bueno si puedes contestarme aqui te lo agradecería...

Answer (score 0):

No se si te sirva esto. Yo levanto un java.jar desde shell:
**archivo.sh**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
logeo=/ruta/del/log/nombre_archivo_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`.log
jar=/ruta/del/jar/Archivo.jar
/opt/java1.5/bin/java -classpath $jar com.paquete.EjecutaClaseConMain > $logeo
gzip $logeo
mv  $logeo.gz /ruta/del/log/comprimido
```

Eso lo levanto con crontab registrando la ruta completa a **archivo.sh** y cuando crontab levanta el sh, se ejecuta el jar. El jar tiene un while que hace que no muera hasta cierta hora de la noche.Cuando el crontab levanta el sh tambien genera un log y va escribiendo en el con system.out.println mientras el jar este vivo. Ese log se puede observar con **tail -f archivo.sh**. Al final del dia cuando el jar muere debido a la hora, el log se comprime y se almacena en una carpeta. Al siguiente dia el crontab vuelve a hacer el mismo ciclo.

Creo que esto es lo contrario a lo que quieres hacer, pero siento que te puede servir.

Comment: Gracias abrahamhs